# Title icon not showing up for android in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-toolbar

I wanted to set title icon in a navigation page. I tried with NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(this, "logo.png"), but showing only in iOS and not in android.

I just want this title icon in one page and rest of the pages with text. iOS displays it correct. For android, I tried to put image in the toolbar style in which it is getting displayed in all the pages which i do not want. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file is included correctly in your iOS project but not in your Android project. You could check that you have definitely included the png file in the Resources/drawable-hdpi (and any other relevant) folder in your Android project. Also, you can check that the build action is set to AndroidResource (right-click on the file in Visual Studio and choose Properties).

Comment: I have the images in all the corresponding folders. The same image i can get in the content pages for Android. Also I have read some discussion regarding the toolbar issue of Android where the icon will not get displayed... but i did not get a proper solution for it. However when I tried to add it in toolbar.axml, the icon is getting displayed in all the pages which i do not want.

Comment: This thread has some things you can try https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52337/navigationpage-settitleicon you can even try setting it in the XAML. Note you need to pass in the content page to SetTitleIcon, not the navigation page, and it must happen in the initializer (not OnNavigatedTo). Good luck!